# Merge two ActiveRecord records into one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

So, I'm in Rails 4 and merge method will not work and cannot get this to work out.

The case is I have two different records, for instance:

```
Model.find_by(:id => 1) && Model.find_by(:id => 2)
```

And I need to merge 2 into one. Than includes all the associations. This model has at least 20 associations and integrity of the data is pretty much valuable.

Desired result would be, in the case of:

```
record_1 = protein: 'chicken'...
record_2 = protein: 'pig'...

result_of_merge = protein: 'chicken, pig'...
```

Not too many clues on the subject. Anyone has faced something similar?

Comment: This is a very specific scenario and I doubt you'll find a ready made solution.

Comment: Not sure I completely understand. What do you mean by "merge" 2 AR objects? Are you trying to create a new Object?

Comment: Yeah, there should be a new object. My mistake

Comment: No idea what your associations are or how you intend those to be "merged" but basic (non-associative) attributes could be merged using `attributes`. `attributes` is a `Hash`. You can use `Hash#merge` with a block to merge the attributes as you see fit and then instantiate a new object with that Hash. e.g. `attrs = record1.attributes.merge(record2.attributes) {|_,old,new| [old,new].join(',')}; Model.new(attrs)`. You will have to provide a significant amount of additional detail recording the model and the desired result to proceed further than this.